# Can't open hyperlink generated by PHP to CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

Recently I have written a small script to write hyperlink to csv.
Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work well. But it does work on libre office.

Here is my code that I tried so far.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://wordpress-website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-file&s=1516893104.5800&form=Apply+with+us&field=CV","Download Application")
=HYPERLINK("http://wordpress-website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-file&s=1516893104.5800&form=Apply+with+us&field=CV";"Download Application")
=HYPERLINK("http://wordpress-website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-file&s=1516893104.5800&form=Apply+with+us&field=CV")
```

Once open the link, it can't download the requested information. When I try to use short url, that seems to work.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of information missing that one would need to answer this.  For example is this `=HYPERLINK` in Excel you wish to open the link?  I doubt that excel will recognize this it probably thinks it's just text, when in a CSV.  And I think excel will recognize a URL unless you turn that off.  http://www.contextures.com/excelhyperlinkfunction.html

Comment: Yes, in the excel it will show up "Download Application" and clickable but can't be opened. In libre office I can open the link by ctrl + click.